# Powermail: captcha always the same

Tags: typo3

i use Powermail 3.12.10 in TYPO3 7.6.16. My problem is, that the implemented Captcha alsways is the same. It does not change when i reload and across browsers. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens if the typo3temp folder is not writeable from TYPO3. So the image can't be overwritten. Check your install tool.
Same question was asked in Slack Channel ext-powermail some days ago.

Comment: Hi Alex, just in the moment i found the reason: wrong UNIX rights: 0644 instead of 0664 on capcha file. No idea why ... Installtool: [SYS][fileCreateMask] = 0664 I am lost :-) Thanks for your answer! Your support is great!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the page is cached. Make sure the plugin is included as `USER_INT`.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was not the file permissions, but the file owner. I set it to `www-data:www-data`, et voila!

To set the owner for the whole directory and subdirectories: `chown -R www-data:www-data <typo3-directory>`

Also, in our (older) version of TYPO3, the captcha file was not in the `typo3temp` directory, but in the according `ext` directory for powermail.